# Null error on Javascript Project. (Null==0?!)

Tags: javascript

There is 2 option here: Score and Wrong.

I want this :

- If answer.value is empty > wrong+1
- If not, score+1.

But its not working.

There is a question here ; 4*0 (answer is 0 right?)

I dont write anything on my answer input. So, > answer.value == null

But, result is score+1. This is not i want.

I guess, answer.value == 0 right here. How can i do what i want?

```
if (result == answer.value) {
  score.innerHTML = Number(score.innerHTML) + 1;
} else if (result != answer.value || answer.value == null) {
  wrong.innerHTML = Number(wrong.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

Complete JavaScript codes and html codes

```js
//idleri alma
var sayi1, sayi2, islem, cevap, btn, dogru, yanlis;

sayi1 = document.getElementById("sayi1");
sayi2 = document.getElementById("sayi2");
islem = document.getElementById("islem");
cevap = document.getElementById("cevap");
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
dogru = document.getElementById("true");
yanlis = document.getElementById("false");

//random sayı oluşturma
function rSayi(ust, alt) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ust - alt)) + alt;
}

function soru() {
  sayi1.innerHTML = rSayi(5, 0);
  sayi2.innerHTML = rSayi(5, 0);
  //islem değişkeni üzerinde değişiklikler
  var islemler = ["+", "-", "/", "*"];
  islem.innerHTML = islemler[rSayi(4, 0)];
  //bölme geldiğinde tam bölünebilme özelliği
  if (islem.innerHTML == "/") {
    while (true) {
      if (sayi1.innerHTML % sayi2.innerHTML == 0) {
        break;
      }
      sayi2.innerHTML = rSayi(50, 0);
    }
  }
  //islem kontrolü
  var sonuc, s1, s2;
  s1 = Number(sayi1.innerHTML) // sayıları
  s2 = Number(sayi2.innerHTML) // number veri türüne geçiş yaptırıyoruz
  switch (islem.innerHTML) {
    case "+":
      sonuc = s1 + s2;
      break;
    case "-":
      sonuc = s1 - s2;
      break;
    case "*":
      sonuc = s1 * s2;
      break;
    case "/":
      sonuc = s1 / s2;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  //dogru yanlis puanlarını arttırmak

  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
  btn.onclick = function() {
    soru();
    var p1, p2;
    p1 = Number(dogru.innerHTML);
    p2 = Number(yanlis.innerHTML);
    if (sonuc == cevap.value) {
      dogru.innerHTML = p1 + 1;
      //dogru.innerHTML = Number(dogru.innerHTML)+1; !diğer yöntem
    } else if (sonuc != cevap.value || cevap.value == null) {
      yanlis.innerHTML = p2 + 1;
      //yanlis.innerHTML = Number(yanlis.innerHTML)+1; !diğer yöntem
    }
  }
}

//events
window.onload = function() {
  soru();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="sayi1">0</div>
    <div id="islem">+</div>
    <div id="sayi2">0</div>
    <div id="equal">=</div>
    <div id="_cevap"><input id="cevap"></div>
    <div id="_btn"><button id="btn">Cevapla</button></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="true">0</div>
    <div id="false">0</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your complete code?

Comment: If `answer` is an HTML element how does the `.value` get set to `"null"`?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but maybe you should use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Please update the question by reproducing the issue....

Comment: answer is not HTML element. My English is bad like i said.

Comment: and my variables language are Turkish so i just Translate to English and post here but i still can share complete code if you guys want.

Comment: I already tried <code>===</code> option. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Mad Yes, can you share the complete code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Here is the compete code : https://paste2.org/p8KfcJKH I wrote //HERE IS THE PROBLEM at the code.

Comment: @Mad Can you include the HTML and JavaScript at the question?

Comment: Here is the HTML too : https://paste2.org/hWmP2nNZ

Comment: I did it @guest271314

Comment: Where is `sonuc` set to `"null"`?

Comment: You can find with CTRL+F > sonuc == null

Comment: `sonuc == null` is comparing the value of `sonuc` to `null`. Where in the code where the value of `sonuc` set to `null`? `sonuc` is defined as a number, not an object with a `.value` property. `sonuc.value` is `undefined`.

Comment: I edited it. I just wrote wrong. But still same problem.

Comment: @Mad  An HTML `<input>` element that does not have a `type` set defaults to `type="text"` where the default `.value` is an empty string `""`. Are you trying to check if `cevap.value` is an empty string `""`? `if (sonuc == cevap.value) {
      dogru.innerHTML = p1 + 1;
    } else if (sonuc != cevap.value || cevap.value == "") {
      yanlis.innerHTML = p2 + 1; }`?

Comment: Yes i did but not work...

Comment: It makes no sense to "down" vote this question. OP is putting forth effort to resolve their own inquiry. OP translated their question from a language other than English to English https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604078/null-error-on-javascript-project-null-0#comment96003924_54604078. When asked for code OP posted the code at the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is `Number('')` is `0` and not `null`

Hence when the `<input >` does not have value, the answer is considered to be 0, which is correct for 4 * 0

Also, use `===` wherever possible to prevent automatic type conversion like this.

What you could do is short-circuit the logic,

```
if(cevap.value === '') // empty is always wrong
  yanlis.innerHTML = p2 + 1;
else {
  ... continue your code here
}
```

updated Code

```js
//idleri alma
var sayi1, sayi2, islem, cevap, btn, dogru, yanlis;

sayi1 = document.getElementById("sayi1");
sayi2 = document.getElementById("sayi2");
islem = document.getElementById("islem");
cevap = document.getElementById("cevap");
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
dogru = document.getElementById("true");
yanlis = document.getElementById("false");

//random sayı oluşturma
function rSayi(ust, alt) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ust - alt)) + alt;
}

function soru() {
  sayi1.innerHTML = rSayi(5, 0);
  sayi2.innerHTML = rSayi(5, 0);
  //islem değişkeni üzerinde değişiklikler
  var islemler = ["+", "-", "/", "*"];
  islem.innerHTML = islemler[rSayi(4, 0)];
  //bölme geldiğinde tam bölünebilme özelliği
  if (islem.innerHTML == "/") {
    while (true) {
      if (sayi1.innerHTML % sayi2.innerHTML == 0) {
        break;
      }
      sayi2.innerHTML = rSayi(50, 0);
    }
  }
  //islem kontrolü
  var sonuc, s1, s2;
  s1 = Number(sayi1.innerHTML) // sayıları
  s2 = Number(sayi2.innerHTML) // number veri türüne geçiş yaptırıyoruz
  switch (islem.innerHTML) {
    case "+":
      sonuc = s1 + s2;
      break;
    case "-":
      sonuc = s1 - s2;
      break;
    case "*":
      sonuc = s1 * s2;
      break;
    case "/":
      sonuc = s1 / s2;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  //dogru yanlis puanlarını arttırmak

  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
  btn.onclick = function() {
    soru();
    var p1, p2;
    p1 = Number(dogru.innerHTML);
    p2 = Number(yanlis.innerHTML);
    if(cevap.value === '') {
      yanlis.innerHTML = p2 + 1;
    } else if (sonuc == cevap.value) {
      dogru.innerHTML = p1 + 1;
      //dogru.innerHTML = Number(dogru.innerHTML)+1; !diğer yöntem
    } else if (sonuc != cevap.value) {
      yanlis.innerHTML = p2 + 1;
      //yanlis.innerHTML = Number(yanlis.innerHTML)+1; !diğer yöntem
    }
  }
}

//events
window.onload = function() {
  soru();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="sayi1">0</div>
    <div id="islem">+</div>
    <div id="sayi2">0</div>
    <div id="equal">=</div>
    <div id="_cevap"><input id="cevap"></div>
    <div id="_btn"><button id="btn">Cevapla</button></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="true">0</div>
    <div id="false">0</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Mad 2 other problems are if sayi2.innerHTML is 0, and islem is '/' then you will get division by 0 error. So consider that as well. Also, do not use innerHTML so much and consider using variables to store the values in JS as innerHTML be very slow